# Conformal changes of metric and Ricci curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, lorentzian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a three dimensional smooth Lorentzian manifold and let $p$ be a fixed point in $M$ and let $S$ be a smooth symmetric tensor of rank two on $T_pM\times T_pM$. Does there exist a smooth conformal factor $c>0$ such that the Ricci curvature of $(M,cg)$ at the point $p$ is equal to $S$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Ricci_tensor Let $c = e^{2\phi}$ and set $\nabla \phi(p) = 0$, you can solve for the Hessian of $\phi$ in terms of the Ricci of $g$ at $p$ and the tensor $S$ at $p$.